# Blazor file not opening

Tags: blazor

I have created a .razor file and have entered some code in the file.
I am unable to open the file and get an error as displayed below:

[image]

After I press enter I get the following:

[image]

Is there a way to repair the .razor file?

Comment: When running the application the file works correctly, it is just when I try to open the file and edit the code it gives me the error

Comment: *.razor file is a text file. Can you open it using e.g. notepad?